# VB6: Using Acrobat Type Library to merge PDFs in VB6

Tags: vb6, adobe, acrobat

I have inherited a VB6 program that uses Crystal Reports 8.5 to run reports & then export the output to a PDF.  It then uses the Adobe Acrobat 5.0 Type Library to merge the resulting PDFs into a single PDF document.  Our problem is that we need to upgrade the Acrobat 5.0 Type Library but it appears that the most current version of Acrobat doesn’t provide a type library that will work with VB6.  Does anyone know the most recent version of Acrobat that is supported within VB6?  Also, does anyone have any suggestions of how this can be upgraded without upgrading the entire application to .Net?  Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

Comment: If Adobe supply a .Net component (anyone know?), you could create a COM-visible wrapper for it. Create a .Net DLL that exposes the functionality and make that DLL COM-visible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd shell out to [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/).  Example from the man page:

> Merge Two or More PDFs into a New Document
>
> `pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf cat output 123.pdf`

Note that if your app is distributed and non-GPL you'll need a commercial license for it, but it's only $24 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same requirement 15 years ago and created a mod in vb6 to do just that:

modMergePDF

Public Function MergePDFFiles

I recently updated the code to handle Acrobat 10.0 Type Library, so you would need to install the latest as of 8/1/2020, Acrobat DC Pro, to...

1. Use the below code
2. Use the compiled MergePDF.exe

Also, the mod adds bookmarks using the file names of the many PDF, with scrub code to
get rid of some ugly file names (you may have to expound upon that if you need to
scrub the file names to bookmark names), into the single pdf file.

Also included a function to generate batch file code:

Public Function BuildBatchFileCode

to call the MergePDF.exe passing in a command
line which consists of the Many pdf directory and the single pdf merged file directory
and file name.  You can also pass in a flag to sort CaseSensitive (Any Capitalized
file names will sort above lowercase) and you can pass in another flag to maintain the .pdf extension in the bookmark name.

Find the MergePDF.exe on git up with all supporting code here:

https://github.com/Brad-Skidmore/MergePDF

Note: the error handling refers to goUtil.utErrorLog  you can also find that on GitHub or you can replace it with your own error handling.
Here's the Mod code: modMergePDF

```
'  http://www.xlsure.com 2020.07.30
' *********************************************************************
'  You are free to use this code within your own applications, but you
'  are expressly forbidden from selling or otherwise distributing this
'  source code without prior written consent.
'  Merge PDF Files - modMergePDF
' *********************************************************************

Option Explicit
'PDF documents must be declared in general declaration space and not local!
Private moMainDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Private moTempDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

Private Property Get msClassName() As String
    msClassName = "modMergePDF"
End Property

Public Function MergePDFFiles(psRawPDFFilesDir As String, _
                                psSinglePDFOutputDir As String, _
                                psSinglePDFOutputName As String, _
                                Optional ByVal pbRemovePdfExtFromBookMark As Boolean = True, _
                                Optional pbCaseSensitiveSort As Boolean = False, _
                                Optional ByVal pbShowError As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo EH
    
    Dim bFirstDoc As Boolean
    Dim sRawPDFFilesDir As String
    Dim sSinglePDFOutputDir As String
    Dim sSinglePDFOutputName As String
    Dim saryFileSort() As String
    Dim sBMName As String
    'Track pos of things
    Dim lBMPageNo As Long
    Dim lPos As Long
    Dim lFile As Long
    Dim lInsertPageAfter As Long
    Dim lNumPages As Long
    Dim lRet As Long
    'Need to use Adobe internal Java Object
    'in order to Add Book marks
    Dim oJSO As Object 'JavaScript Object
    Dim oBookMarkRoot As Object
    'File I/O
    Dim oFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim oFile As Scripting.File
    Dim oFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    
    sRawPDFFilesDir = psRawPDFFilesDir
    'ensure backslash for the 2 b merged PDF files directory
    If StrComp(Right(sRawPDFFilesDir, 1), "\", vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
        sRawPDFFilesDir = sRawPDFFilesDir & "\"
        psRawPDFFilesDir = sRawPDFFilesDir
    End If

    sSinglePDFOutputDir = psSinglePDFOutputDir
    sSinglePDFOutputName = psSinglePDFOutputName
    
    'ensure .pdf for the PDFOutputName (If it's CAP .PDF should be okay)
    If StrComp(Right(sSinglePDFOutputName, 4), ".pdf", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        sSinglePDFOutputName = sSinglePDFOutputName & ".pdf"
        psSinglePDFOutputName = sSinglePDFOutputName
    End If

    Set oFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sRawPDFFilesDir)
    
    bFirstDoc = True

    If oFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'Because the FSO folder files collection does not allow for
    'Native sorting, need to plug all the files into an array and sort that motha
    ReDim saryFileSort(1 To oFolder.Files.Count)
    lFile = 0
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        lFile = lFile + 1
        saryFileSort(lFile) = oFile.Name
    Next
    
    'Once they is all in der sor the array
    'Sort is Case Sensitive
    If pbCaseSensitiveSort Then
        goUtil.utBubbleSort saryFileSort
    End If
    
    For lFile = 1 To UBound(saryFileSort, 1)
        If LCase(Right(saryFileSort(lFile), 4)) = ".pdf" Then
            If bFirstDoc Then
                bFirstDoc = False
                Set moMainDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc") 'New AcroPDDoc
                lRet = moMainDoc.Open(sRawPDFFilesDir & saryFileSort(lFile))
                Set oJSO = moMainDoc.GetJSObject
                Set oBookMarkRoot = oJSO.BookMarkRoot
                sBMName = saryFileSort(lFile)
                lPos = InStr(1, sBMName, "_{", vbBinaryCompare)
                If lPos > 0 Then
                    sBMName = left(sBMName, lPos - 1) & ".pdf"
                End If
                If pbRemovePdfExtFromBookMark Then
                    sBMName = Replace(sBMName, ".pdf", vbNullString, , , vbTextCompare)
                End If
                lRet = oBookMarkRoot.CreateChild(sBMName, "this.pageNum =0", lFile - 1)
            Else
                Set moTempDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc") 'New AcroPDDoc
                lRet = moTempDoc.Open(sRawPDFFilesDir & saryFileSort(lFile))
                'get the Book mark page number before the actual instert of new pages
                lBMPageNo = moMainDoc.GetNumPages
                lInsertPageAfter = lBMPageNo - 1
                lNumPages = moTempDoc.GetNumPages
                lRet = moMainDoc.InsertPages(lInsertPageAfter, moTempDoc, 0, lNumPages, 0)
                moTempDoc.Close
                If lRet = 0 Then
                    sBMName = saryFileSort(lFile)
                    lPos = InStr(1, sBMName, "_{", vbBinaryCompare)
                    If lPos > 0 Then
                        sBMName = left(sBMName, lPos - 1) & ".pdf"
                    End If
                    'Need to copy the errored document over to be included in the enitre document
                    goUtil.utCopyFile sRawPDFFilesDir & saryFileSort(lFile), sSinglePDFOutputDir & "\" & sBMName
                    sBMName = "PDF Insert Page Error_" & sBMName
                Else
                    sBMName = saryFileSort(lFile)
                    lPos = InStr(1, sBMName, "_{", vbBinaryCompare)
                    If lPos > 0 Then
                        sBMName = left(sBMName, lPos - 1) & ".pdf"
                    End If
                End If
                If pbRemovePdfExtFromBookMark Then
                    sBMName = Replace(sBMName, ".pdf", vbNullString, , , vbTextCompare)
                End If
                lRet = oBookMarkRoot.CreateChild(sBMName, "this.pageNum =" & lBMPageNo, lFile - 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    lRet = moMainDoc.Save(1, sSinglePDFOutputDir & "\" & sSinglePDFOutputName)
    moMainDoc.Close
    
    MergePDFFiles = True
    
CLEAN_UP:
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oBookMarkRoot = Nothing
    Set oJSO = Nothing
    Set moMainDoc = Nothing
    Set moTempDoc = Nothing
    
    Exit Function
EH:
    goUtil.utErrorLog Err, App.EXEName, msClassName, "Public Function MergePDFFiles", pbShowError
End Function

Public Function BuildBatchFileCode(psRawPDFFilesDir As String, _
                                    psSinglePDFOutputDir As String, _
                                    psSinglePDFOutputName As String, _
                                    pbRemovePdfExtFromBookMark As Boolean, _
                                    pbCaseSensitiveSort As Boolean) As String
    
    On Error GoTo EH
    
    Dim sRawPDFFilesDir As String: sRawPDFFilesDir = psRawPDFFilesDir
    Dim sSinglePDFOutputDir As String: sSinglePDFOutputDir = psSinglePDFOutputDir
    Dim sSinglePDFOutputName As String: sSinglePDFOutputName = psSinglePDFOutputName
    Dim bRemovePdfExtFromBookMark As Boolean: bRemovePdfExtFromBookMark = pbRemovePdfExtFromBookMark

    'ensure backslash for the 2 b merged PDF files directory
    If StrComp(Right(sRawPDFFilesDir, 1), "\", vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
        sRawPDFFilesDir = sRawPDFFilesDir & "\"
        psRawPDFFilesDir = sRawPDFFilesDir
    End If

    'ensure .pdf for the PDFOutputName (If it's CAP .PDF should be okay)
    If StrComp(Right(sSinglePDFOutputName, 3), ".pdf", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        sSinglePDFOutputName = sSinglePDFOutputName & ".pdf"
        psSinglePDFOutputName = sSinglePDFOutputName
    End If
    
    Dim sCommandLine As String
    
    sCommandLine = "RawPDFFilesDir|" & sRawPDFFilesDir _
                    & "|SinglePDFOutputDir|" & sSinglePDFOutputDir _
                    & "|SinglePDFOutputName|" & sSinglePDFOutputName _
                    & "|RemovePdfExtFromBookMark|" & CStr(bRemovePdfExtFromBookMark) _
                    & "|CaseSensitiveSort|" & CStr(pbCaseSensitiveSort)

    BuildBatchFileCode = """" & App.Path & "\" & App.EXEName & ".exe"" """ & sCommandLine
    Exit Function
EH:
    goUtil.utErrorLog Err, App.EXEName, msClassName, "Public Function BuildBatchFileCode"
End Function
```